# Disable Disk Fragmentation Analysis - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, defrag, defragmentation

I have been asked to look into disabling the fragmentation analysis that Windows performs automatically for one of our servers.  I have verified that the Disk Defrag tool shows automatic defragmentation is disabled, that the Windows "ScheduledDefrag" job in Task Scheduler is disabled, and that indeed defragmentation is not being performed automatically, but event logs show that the disk is still being analyzed for fragmentation every morning around 7am.

Is there a way to disable the fragmentation analysis as well as the defragmentation process itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would double check whether defrag is scheduled or not by running the Disk Defrag tool and checking it there.

Comment: @joeqwerty, thank you for the suggestion, I had forgotten to include that in the original question. I have edited it to include the fact that the Disk Defragmenter tool shows that automatic defrag is disabled.